# reactJS render which calls a function with parameters can not compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a reactJS application with the following code to dynamically render output:

```
    renderData = () => {   

    return this.state.data.map( data => (
        <div>
            <div className="oldscanFont">
                <img className="resize" src={data.galleryURL}></img><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Price:&nbsp; {data.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]['__value__']}</label><br />
                <label> {data.title} </label>
            </div>                    
            <div>
                <button className="btnStartScan"
                    type='button'     
                    onClick={() => { 
                    this.saveData(this.barcode, {data.title}, {data.galleryURL}, {data.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]['__value__']} );
                    }}>
                    Save
                </button>                    
            </div> 
        </div>
    ) )
}
```

What I would like to do is call the function this.saveData when a user clicks on the generated button.  In addition, I want to pass a few parameters to saveData.  The problem is that my editor flags the '.' in all the parameters I wish to pass other than this.barcode.  In other words, I get flagged on the '.' in the parameter {data.title}.  {data.title} is valid as it appears a few  lines above the call of the saveData function.

What would the correct syntax be for me to pass these few parameters to the saveData function?

Thank you.

Comment: Because you are wrapping it in `{}`, you don't do that in js to reference a variable.  That is for binding data to html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do use braces again inside braces. Braces means you are referring to Javascript code in JSX. You can treat everything inside a pair of braces as pure JS. Remove the braces inside your onClick property like below:

```
<button className="btnStartScan"
        type='button'     
        onClick={() => { 
            this.saveData(this.barcode, data.title, data.galleryURL, data.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]['__value__'] );
        }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your objects need keys:

```
this.saveData(this.barcode, {data.title}, {data.galleryURL}, {data.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]['__value__']} );
```

Should be:

```
this.saveData(this.barcode, {title: data.title}, {galleryUrl: data.galleryURL}, {value: data.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]['__value__']} );
```

You can use the object key/value shorthand but you have to use an identifier not an expression:

```
const { title, galleryURL } = data;
const value = data.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]['__value__'];

this.saveData(this.barcode, {title}, {galleryURL}, {value} );
```

Also I'm not sure if your intention is to pass objects to `saveData`. You don't need to wrap variables in `{}` in JSX when you're already in an escaped group (the value of `onClick`).

Answer (score 0):

You should utilise both dataset and value attributes of the button, along with the click handler as a reference.

```
<button 
    value={mainValueVariable}
    data-title={data.title}
    data-gallery-url={data.galleryUrl}
    className="btnStartScan" 
    type='button' 
    onClick={this.saveData}>
    Save
</button>
```

Then in the click handler function, that also exists inside your Component Class, where your current renderData method is:

```
saveData = event => {
    const { value, dataset } = event.target
    const { galleryUrl, title } = dataset;

    ... do something with value and dataset thingies
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to pass the data object inside your function:

```
this.saveData(this.barcode,data)
```

Then, in the saveData function, utilize the data options:

```
saveData(barcode, data) {
const {title, galleryURL, sellingStatus} = data
//now, work through title, galleryURL, sellingStatus
```